# Does American Community Survey publish individual data?

Tags: dataset

It seems that American Community Survey only gives "aggregate" data. I would like to know if they publish the random sampled individual data as well? For example, do they publish data on the ages or sex of a certain number of individuals across america? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ReadMe file](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/tech_docs/pums/ACS2012_2016_PUMS_README.pdf) for 2012-2016 PUMS (the responses to the ACS), the data comprise individual responses.

> The Public Use Microdata Sample (PUMS) contains a sample of actual responses to the American Community Survey (ACS). The PUMS dataset includes variables for nearly every question on the survey, as well as many new variables that were derived after the fact from multiple survey responses (such as poverty status). Each record in the file represents a single person, or--in the household-level dataset--a single housing unit. In the person-level file, individuals are organized into households, making possible the study of people within the contexts of their families and other household members. PUMS files for an individual year, such as 2016, contain data on approximately one percent of the United States population. PUMS files covering a five-year period, such as 2012-2016, contain data on approximately five percent of the United States population.